# How to rotate GLSurfaceView?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I try to use setRotation() on my GLSurfaceView, but the view seems not rotate around the pivot which is the center of  the screen. the code like below:

```
class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    private float mCurRotation = 0.0f;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        mCurRotation = mCurRotation + 10;
        setRotation(mCurRotation);
    }
}
```

Is there any body know the reason and teach me how to rotate my GLSurfaceView?

Comment: Here is posted a good answer on how to make it using OpenGL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703984/rotating-android-camera-preview-by-90-degrees-on-glsurfaceview-using-opengl-2-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to your expectation, methods of `View` doesn't work well.

GLSurfaceView punches a hole to display underneath surface. Actually it has only transparent pixels.

If you want to rotate your image, you have to use OpenGL operations.

Comment: thanks a lot, actually we use opengl to solve the problem finally.

Comment: can you post how you solved the problem I am in same problem.