# How to zoom a portion in android video view?

Tags: android, android-videoview, textureview

I have a rtsp live stream to show in a videoview. This stream consist output of 4 cameras. Like in the figure, I want to enlarge respective camera and fit in view, when user press a camera button. The stream that I have is single channel..[image: Initial view]

[image: Camera selected view]

Comment: Maybe use a `GLSurfaceView`, then changing the geometry is easy. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59524927/how-to-create-multiple-camera2-previews-in-most-efficient-way) for some discussion.