# Render SurfaceTexture on GLSurfaceView - Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, androidx, glsurfaceview, android-camerax

I have a CameraX Preview that provides me with a SurfaceTexture with the camera feed:

```
    Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();        

    preview.setPreviewSurfaceProvider((resolution, surfaceReleaseFuture) -> {
        SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(0);
        surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(resolution.getWidth(), resolution.getHeight());
        final Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

        // Once surfaceReleaseFuture completes, the Surface and SurfaceTexture
        // are no longer used by the camera hence safe to close.
        surfaceReleaseFuture.addListener(() -> {
            surface.release();
            surfaceTexture.release();
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this.reactContext));

        // Return the Surface back in a ListenableFuture
        return Futures.immediateFuture(surface);
    });
```

The code is run inside a class extending  a `GLSurfaceView` on component mount and the concern I have is how can I render the camera feed in `onDrawFrame`? I read that I would have to binf `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` for that, but have no idea how to implement that and then render the texture 'fullscreen' on the `GLSurfaceView`.

Comment: There are plenty of code samples available online. [Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703984/rotating-android-camera-preview-by-90-degrees-on-glsurfaceview-using-opengl-2-0).

Comment: Thank you, this works! Due to a different use case and description, I couldn't find it earlier

Comment: Thanks to @greeble31, finally found the answer on thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703984/rotating-android-camera-preview-by-90-degrees-on-glsurfaceview-using-opengl-2-0